# Using Facebook API to pull events from a page that has an age restriction?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, wordpress

I am using a plugin from Modern Tribe which pulls Facebook events into their other plugin "The Events Calendar" for Wordpress(http://tri.be/shop/facebook-events/). Unfortunately I am getting an error: "Facebook API Error: Unsupported get request." I reported this to Modern Tribe and they informed me that this was due to the page having age restricted content(it's for a beer company). They basically told me I was SOL and there was nothing that could be done, but I wanted to check here before throwing in the towel.

Couldn't I use an access token of a profile that is of age to bypass this somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having this problem too. Seeing as most events are for bars, etc. this seems ridiculous. Did you find any way around it?

Comment: Nope, looks like it's not possible, at least from the server-side :/ The only way to pull event data from age-restricted pages is to use an access token from a Facebook user who is of age.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.  And even if there was a workaround, your Key's would get banned faster than you could say "Microsoft Owns Facebook".